# How can I identify the element I am looking for prior to it being loaded using WebDriverWait

Tags: windows, selenium-webdriver, appium, webdriverwait, appium-desktop

I'm writing a test for a WPF desktop application using Appium. I need to wait for an element to appear. I have the following code:

```
WebDriverWait testWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));
            
var userName = driver.FindElementByName("userNameBox");

testWait.Until(pred => userName.Displayed);
```

This code fails due to the userName variable not being set (second line) - 'An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.'

Obviously this is because the element isn't loaded yet - which is the point of the code. But how else do I identify the element that I am looking for ahead of it being loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for this element visibility with `ExpectedConditions`.
Something like this:

```
testWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("userNameBox")));
```

Comment: I'm not totally sure about the syntax here. You didn't mention your binding language... This is how it looks in Java / Selenium. In case you are coding in C# it may be some uppercase where I use lowercase :) etc.

Comment: Thanks, will try this!